# kustomize how to target replacement in every array

Tags: kustomize

As per the examples https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/replacements/

one can target specific array items like such `spec.template.spec.containers.[name=hello].env.[name=SECRET_TOKEN].value`

But how do we target every array item ?

Tried `-` as below but it is replacing only the last occurrence.

```
fieldPaths:
     - spec.http.-.route.0.destination.host
```

Here is my kustomization.yaml

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: ef
images:
- name: gateway-image
resources:
- configmap.yaml
- virtual-services.yaml
replacements:
- source:
    kind: ConfigMap
    fieldPath: data.HOST
  targets:
  - select:
      kind: VirtualService
    fieldPaths:
     - spec.http.-.route.0.destination.host
    options:
      create: true
```

Here is my target yaml service-entries.yaml - I am expect that the HOST gets replaced in both places.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: v-rules-1
spec:
  hosts:
    - EXTERNAL-HOST
  gateways:
    - istio-system/default-gateway
    - mesh
  http: # note these are ordered - first rule matching wins
  - match:
    - uri:
       prefix: /foo
    route:
      - destination:
          host: PLACEHOLDER1
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /bar
    route:
      - destination:
          host: PLACEHOLDER2
```

But as you can see below the results has only the last value:-

```
kustomize build .
```

produces this. As you can see example.com appears correctly in the last entry only - PLACEHOLDE1 is unaffected:-

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  HOST: example.com
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: gateway-configmap
  namespace: ef
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: v-rules-1
  namespace: ef
spec:
  gateways:
  - istio-system/default-gateway
  - mesh
  hosts:
  - EXTERNAL-HOST
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /foo
    route:
    - destination:
        host: PLACEHOLDER1
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /bar
    route:
    - destination:
        host: example.com
```

So question is how do we replace *every* array element ? What is the syntax for fieldPath.

kustomize version is 4.2.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can now use `*` as wildcard:

```
spec.http.*.route.0.destination.host
```

This was added in 2022:
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/4053

Comment: It's already implemented using * as wildcard: `- spec.http.*.route.0.destination.host`